Example of a PID (cardinality infinite ) with $n$ Maximal ideals
For every $n\in \Bbb{N}$, can we find a PID (cardinality infinite) with exactly $n$ Maximal ideals?
This question was asked to me in an interview. They told me to use localisation but I still don't have any idea about it. I searched about it after the interview and couldn't find anything.

Duplicate of  Examples of PID's with finitely many maximal ideals. $\ \ $

The linked question tells about example of finitely many maximal ideals but my question is more general. I wanted example of a PID  having exactly n maximal ideals for any given natural number n.

Please read the linked answer - it does exactly what you seek (same as the answer below).

Choose $n$ distinct maximal ideals in $\mathbb{Z}$, say $m_1,\dots,m_n$. Now consider the multiplicative set $S=\mathbb{Z}\setminus\bigcup_{i=1}^nm_i$. Then the localization $\mathbb{Z}_S$ has exactly $n$ maximal ideals by the classical correspondence theorem of ideals in a ring and its localization, namely $m_{i,S}=\{\frac{m}{s}\mid m\in m_i,\ s\in S\}$. Notice that this works for essentially all PID's that have more then $n$ maximal ideals.

Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see here.
